# Masonry UL LI lister, images don't fit together

Tags: jquery, masonry

I'm trying to use [isotope](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/layout-modes/masonry.html) to make images show in a `masonry` style.

I've included the following in my header:

```
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.isotope/2.2.0/isotope.pkgd.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            var $container = $('.album-lister');
            $container.isotope({
                itemSelector: '.thumb',
                masonry: {
                    columnWidth: 100
                }
            })
        </script>
```

My HTML looks like this:

```
<ul class="album-lister">
    <li class="thumb"><img src="http://localhost/57898d673ae1f7482d04ab1c3de60363.jpg"></li>
    <li class="thumb"><img src="http://localhost/behind_scenes_1.jpg"></li>
    <li class="thumb"><img src="http://localhost/behind_scenes_2.jpg"></li>
    <li class="thumb"><img src="http://localhostbehind_scenes_3.jpg"></li>
</ul>
```

I've added the following CSS:

```
.album-lister .thumb img{ max-width: 100%;height:auto;}
.album-lister .thumb{width:20%;}
```

What am I missing? Nothing is resized to 100px and there is no difference.

Edit: I have tried using imagesLoaded as suggested:

```
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.isotope/2.2.0/isotope.pkgd.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://imagesloaded.desandro.com/imagesloaded.pkgd.min.js"></script>
```

var $container = $('.album-lister').imagesLoaded( function() {
                    $container.isotope({
                        itemSelector: '.thumb',
                        layoutMode: 'fitRows',
                        masonry: {
                          columnWidth: 100
                        }
                    });
                });

Comment: Have updated my answer, you're a little bit out.

Comment: Just FYI - the answer by Makinovic works.....becuase you already have the images cached in your browser.  Now try it again incognito.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

 jQuery(document).ready(function () {
            var $container = $('.album-lister');
            $container.isotope({
                itemSelector: '.thumb',
                masonry: {
                    columnWidth: 100
                }
            })

  });
```

Comment: I've tried this, and although it makes it do something I cannot work out how to make it use the specified column width. It doesn't make the columns 100px wide.

Answer (score 0):

You are firing the JS in the head before the images are loaded.  The best way to handle this is to use imagesLoaded, which will wait until the images are loaded before Isotope runs.  That is better than waiting for `$(document).ready()` because Isotope needs to know the image sizes to handle the layout properly, and it only gets them after they have loaded.

Read more here;

http://isotope.metafizzy.co/appendix.html

Your code would be;

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
  var $container = $('#album-lister');

  $container.imagesLoaded( function(){
      $container.isotope({
          itemSelector: '.thumb',
          layoutMode: 'fitRows',
          masonry: {
              columnWidth: 100
          }
      });
  });
});
```

And I see you have to load the imagesLoaded plugin separately now, it was actually taken over by Dessandro who wrote Isotope;

https://github.com/desandro/imagesloaded

Here is some more debugging on another SO thread.

[Isotope display gallery after images loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15177919/isotope-display-gallery-after-images-loaded)

Just a few final points - I would use an id for the container rather than a class and I would not have each item as an unordered list;

```
<div id="album-lister">
    <div class="thumb"><img src="http://localhost/57898d673ae1f7482d04ab1c3de60363.jpg"></div>
    <div class="thumb"><img src="http://localhost/behind_scenes_1.jpg"></div>
    <div class="thumb"><img src="http://localhost/behind_scenes_2.jpg"></div>
    <div class="thumb"><img src="http://localhostbehind_scenes_3.jpg"></div>
</div>
```

Semantically it's not a list and you will just make your CSS life harder by marking it up like that.

Comment: Sorry I have edited to explain - you would include that in `$(document).ready()` and you would make sure you included the imagesLoaded plugin.  That's the `imagesloaded.js` file in the Github link

Comment: Hi there, this works but all my images just output full width. They don't fit together at all. If I set the width with CSS then the images fit together but the bottom 5 all layer on top of each other weirdly. Am I misunderstanding the use of columnWidth? It doesn't actually do anything?

Comment: For example I expected setting columnWidth to 100 would give me a grid that fits together with the columns being 100px wide. But it doesn't actually do anything. Where do I set the width?

Comment: What happens if you add `layoutMode: 'fitColumns'` in the line above masonry?  http://isotope.metafizzy.co/layout-modes.html

Comment: For reference, if I set everything to a width with CSS and make it inline-block it does this, which is what is expected. But no masonry in sight: http://grab.by/GJwe

Comment: If I turn off all that styling then it just outputs the images at their size: http://grab.by/GJwo

Comment: See my final amends, I'll leave it at that, that's the best I can do.

Comment: Thanks but that's exactly what I've got. Do you know of a masonry-esque plugin that does work? This one doesn't seem to do anything.